# MYSQL - which variable type should I choose when hosting unknown URL?

Tags: mysql, url, text, types, string-length

I need to store a URL in one of my tables. Problem is, I don't know and can't assume its length.

I would like to know what variable type should I use (I was thinking about `TEXT` but i'm not sure because someone can submit a crazy-long URLs - they must not get cut)

Thanks!

Comment: store it as varchar(2000) with a sequenceID and if it's greater than 2000 characters have multiple rows.  Join them back together later.  that way you can have infinite size if needed.  No risk of running out of space if it's a crazy-long url as you just add rows as needed breaking it into 2000 character chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern versions of MySQL support very long `VARCHAR` strings, so you can try with something like `VARCHAR(2048)` or use a `TEXT` field if you're concerned they could be even longer, that allows up to 64K characters.

Although there are historical reasons for keeping URLs relatively short, tradition holds they should be under 1500 characters, it's not uncommon to see some sites wildly exceed this. That being said, 64K should suffice and anything longer than that is a severe outlier.

Comment: If I use the `TEXT` field, and I have for example 2 strings: "google.com" and a very long one - will they both take the same amount of storage because of their types, or the storage is taken by the string length?

Comment: @ItayGanor `VARCHAR` only takes as much as is needed, not the full length specified in the column definition; that is the main difference between it and `CHAR`. (However, if you working with a table using the MyISAM engine, this dynamic sizing can make using the table a little slower.)

Comment: @Uueerdo It's worth noting that MyISAM shouldn't be used for new databases. It's a terribly creaky engine that's only there for legacy support.

Comment: Space for a `VARCHAR` column is allocated as necessary, that's what the `VAR` part means. By contrast `CHAR` always allocates the maximum amount. `TEXT` columns work the same way in principle.

Comment: @tadman agreed, it's lack of support for so many features pretty much rules it out in my opinion, except in the rare cases where it's few benefits are absolutely needed.